# Google Analytics monthly report to be sent weekly?

Tags: google-analytics

It is possible to choose an interval for a certain Google Analytics report?
I would like to be able to send a monthly report (for the last 30 days) on weekly basis.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this is currently possible through the Google Analytics website, but you could use the [Google Analytics Spreadsheet Add-on](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/google-analytics-spreadsheet-add-on) to achieve a very similar result.

Answer (score 0):

You can Share almost any report in GA
Use Email option and set frequency Weekly.

I am new here so cant post image, would have posted screenshot otherwise.